# pandas dataframe isin greater than value

Tags: python

I have a df `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})` and I would like to use `df.isin()` and find values greater than x. I was trying something like `df.isin( < 3 )`. The end output would look like

```
    col1
0   False
1   False
2   True
3   True
4   True
5   True`
```

What would a solution be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.isin(range(3,7))` but using `df >= 3` would also produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your dataframe with filtering on some condition, you can do it like this:

```
df.loc[df['col1'] < 3]
```

If you need exactly the output in your question, then it's even more simple:

```
df['col1'] < 3
```